# TTouchKeyboard as numeric keypad without the /*+- keys

Tags: delphi, vcl, virtual-keyboard

I'm using the standard TTouchKeyboard and I would like to show a numeric keypad without the /*+- keys.
Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Possibly yes - with custom keyboard layout. See [Hacking the TTouchKeyboard serie](http://chrisbensen.blogspot.com/2009/12/hacking-ttouchkeyboard-part-i.html)

Comment: Solved, for a nice example see http://decoding.dax.ru/practic/TouchKeyboard/TouchKeyboard.html

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer so it can eventually help someone in the future.